# how to find securely all mysql databases on a linux server

Tags: mysql, linux

The post's title says almost everything:

How do I get a list of all mysql databases on a linux server?

I have read somewhere that there could be restrictions on the view a mysql user has on the list of available databases.

But I need a complete list of all mysql databases installed on a particular linux server (OpenSuse 13.1 in this case).

Comment: *"there could be restrictions on the view a mysql user has"* - That's why you'd do this as an administrator.  Though what do you mean by a "complete list"?  Can there be other MySQL instances running on the same server with their own databases?  Are you also interested in other non-MySQL database servers running on that host?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish and why?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [`SHOW DATABASES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html)

```
SHOW {DATABASES | SCHEMAS}
    [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

> SHOW DATABASES lists the databases on the MySQL server host. SHOW
>   SCHEMAS is a synonym for SHOW DATABASES. The LIKE clause, if present,
>   indicates which database names to match. The WHERE clause can be given
>   to select rows using more general conditions

**However,** you can see only those databases for which you have some kind of privilege, unless you have the global `SHOW DATABASES` privilege.

---

**Another alternative** is using [`mysqlshow`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlshow.html) client.

> The mysqlshow client can be used to quickly see which databases
>   exist, their tables, or a table's columns or indexes.

Comment: Thx. How can I find out whether the user in question (which is not root in this case) HAS the global SHOW DATABASES priviledge?

Comment: @wobits well try running the command. You shall get your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You list all databases by executing:

```
mysql -u<username> -p<password> -e"SHOW DATABASES"
```

If you do not have access to the mysql server you could also check which databases exists by checking the `/var/lib/mysql` folder, which will contain a separate folder for each database:

```
ls -l /var/lib/mysql

total 28692
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql        0 May 24  2017 debian-5.5.flag
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  5242880 Oct  6 16:50 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  5242880 Jul 10  2015 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 18874368 Jan 17  2018 ibdata1
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 May 24  2017 mysql
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql        6 May 24  2017 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 May 24  2017 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jul 10  2015 scotchbox
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jan 17  2018 wp
```

As you can see in the above output there is 4 databases: `mysql`, `performance_schema`, `scotchbox` and `wp`.

Comment: So, do I get it right that the user "root" will normally have sufficient privileges to show ALL exisiting databases?

Comment: @wobits - That was just an example username to connect to the mysql server.